# Make a text input dialog in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to make a Power BI template, where upon open, will prompt user to input the path to the source data file. How can I do that, with what language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Power BI Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-templates) and [connection specific parameters](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/power-bi-introduction-working-with-parameters-in-power-bi-desktop-part-4/) to achieve that.

First create your report the normal way. When it is ready, define a text parameter for the file name - click `Transform data` to open `Power Query Editor`, and then click `Manage parameters` and add a new parameter:

[image]

Make sure the type is `Text` and set the current value to be the path to the file that you used to build the report. The open your query (or queries) in the `Advanced editor` (right click the query) to show the M code and locate the file name and path to the source file:

[image]

Change the hard-coded file name and path with the name of the parameter defined above:

[image]

Close and apply `Power Query Editor` and from `File` -> `Save as` save your report as a template (.pbit file). When this template file is opened, it will prompt for entering values for the defined parameters, i.e. for the path to the data source file:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm marking this as answer.